# exclude specific rows based on time conditions in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I really don't understand why my previous question was closed because at least one user MT0 understood it correctly so it doesn't see that I didn't described my problem correct.

his solution is here https://dbfiddle.uk/DZNetwsh

MT0 good job but there is one issue with your solution, the records I provided are not stored in a table but they are selected in WITH clause with many table joins m distinct and group by. Because of that I get an Ora error on this line of code you provided " AND t.ROWID = e.rid ".

I post the record again with some new row. in our production table there are many rows with a date 01-01-9999 which means the order is still open, like for brand ppp.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (brand, type, start_date, end_date) AS
  SELECT 'abc', 'W', DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 'A', DATE '2020-07-01', DATE '2020-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 'W', DATE '2020-09-01', DATE '2020-09-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mmm', 'W', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-03-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mmm', 'W', DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mmm', 'A', DATE '2023-07-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', 'W', DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', 'A', DATE '2019-01-01', DATE '2024-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'zzz', 'W', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'zzz', 'A', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'qqq', 'W', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-03-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'qqq', 'W', DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'qqq', 'A', DATE '2023-01-02', DATE '2023-09-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ppp', 'A', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '9999-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ppp', 'W', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2024-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ppp', 'W', DATE '2021-09-01', DATE '2021-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'uuu', 'W', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2023-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'uuu', 'W', DATE '2023-09-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'uuu', 'A', DATE '2023-01-02', DATE '2023-08-31' FROM DUAL;
```

it will be sufficient if I get just the rows of type A which are valid for my use case.

Records of type W have always priority that means they are always valid and should be in the output. If it is not possible then valid records of type A will do as well.

records of type A are not valid if they didn't/don't run alone in some point in time. for example for brand mmm or zzz the type A is fully covered by one record of type W. for brand qqq where the record is covered first partialy by both records of type W, there is no space between them. But for brand uuu the record of type A will pass because it is partialy covered but there is time frame from 1.7.2022-31.8.2023 where the record of type A runs alone so it will pass.

there is one issue in the solutions from user MT0 for brand ppp. the open records with date 01-01-9999 will pass correctly but as I mentioned above, all records of type W must pass.

I don;t know it this solution will work for 30mil records with many records with date 01-01-9999 because I tried function that can check each day of an record of type A if there is a matching time frame of at least one record of type W but this solution requires lot of PL and SQl switching and is the worst method. Another solution was scaffoling which generates the same record of type A based on number of days of the date ranges but this generates so many rows especially for open records with date 01-01-9999. this will use up temp tablespace.

what else can be done?

Comment: Can you share the output rows you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate all the continuous type `W` ranges and check to see if the type `A` rows are completely contained in a `W` range and those rows are not passed and then pass all the other rows:

```sql
WITH continuous_w_ranges (brand, start_date, end_date) AS (
  SELECT brand, start_date, end_date
  FROM   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   table_name
    WHERE type = 'W'
  )
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
    PARTITION BY brand
    ORDER BY start_date, end_date
    MEASURES
      FIRST(start_date) AS start_date,
      MAX(end_date)     AS end_date
    PATTERN ( continuing_range* next_range )
    DEFINE
      continuing_range AS MAX(end_date) + 1 >= NEXT(start_date) 
  )
)
SELECT brand,
       type,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       CASE
       WHEN type = 'A'
       AND  EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM   continuous_w_ranges w
              WHERE  w.brand = a.brand
              AND    w.start_date <= a.start_date
              AND    a.end_date <= w.end_date
            )
       THEN 'not pass'
       ELSE 'pass'
       END AS pass
FROM   table_name a
ORDER BY brand, start_date;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (brand, type, start_date, end_date) AS
  SELECT 'abc', 'W', DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 'A', DATE '2020-07-01', DATE '2020-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 'W', DATE '2020-09-01', DATE '2020-09-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mmm', 'W', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-03-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mmm', 'W', DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mmm', 'A', DATE '2023-07-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', 'W', DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', 'A', DATE '2019-01-01', DATE '2024-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'zzz', 'W', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'zzz', 'A', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'qqq', 'W', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-03-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'qqq', 'W', DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'qqq', 'A', DATE '2023-01-02', DATE '2023-09-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ppp', 'A', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '9999-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ppp', 'W', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2024-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ppp', 'W', DATE '2021-09-01', DATE '2021-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'uuu', 'W', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2023-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'uuu', 'W', DATE '2023-09-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'uuu', 'A', DATE '2023-01-02', DATE '2023-08-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| BRAND | TYPE | START_DATE | END_DATE | PASS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | W | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-06-30 00:00:00 | pass |
| abc | A | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| abc | W | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 2020-09-30 00:00:00 | pass |
| mmm | W | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| mmm | W | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| mmm | A | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | not pass |
| ppp | W | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| ppp | W | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| ppp | A | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 9999-01-01 00:00:00 | pass |
| qqq | W | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| qqq | A | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 2023-09-30 00:00:00 | not pass |
| qqq | W | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| uuu | W | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | pass |
| uuu | A | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 2023-08-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| uuu | W | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| xyz | A | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| xyz | W | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| zzz | W | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| zzz | A | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | not pass |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qWKfF0ma)

Answer (score 1):

`ROWID` is a pseudo-column that is a unique reference (effectively a pointer) to a row of a table. If you have a result set that is not tied to a table and cannot use `ROWID` then all you need to do is replace that with any other unique identifier for a row; and if that does not exist then generate one using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function.

For example:

```sql
WITH table_name (brand, type, start_date, end_date) AS (
  SELECT 'abc', 'W', DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 'A', DATE '2020-07-01', DATE '2020-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 'W', DATE '2020-09-01', DATE '2020-09-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mmm', 'W', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-03-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mmm', 'W', DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mmm', 'A', DATE '2023-07-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', 'W', DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', 'A', DATE '2019-01-01', DATE '2024-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'zzz', 'W', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'zzz', 'A', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'qqq', 'W', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-03-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'qqq', 'W', DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'qqq', 'A', DATE '2023-01-02', DATE '2023-09-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ppp', 'A', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '9999-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ppp', 'W', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2024-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ppp', 'W', DATE '2021-09-01', DATE '2021-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'uuu', 'W', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2023-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'uuu', 'W', DATE '2023-09-01', DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'uuu', 'A', DATE '2023-01-02', DATE '2023-08-31' FROM DUAL
),
data (brand, type, start_date, end_date, rn) AS (
  SELECT brand,
         type,
         start_date,
         end_date + 1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY brand, start_date)
  FROM   table_name t
)
SELECT brand,
       type,
       start_date,
       end_date - 1 AS end_date,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   (
           SELECT brand,
                  type,
                  dt AS start_date,
                  CASE
                  WHEN SUM(CASE type WHEN 'W' THEN start_end END)
                         OVER (PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY dt) > 0
                  THEN LAST_VALUE(CASE type WHEN 'W' THEN rn END)
                         IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY dt)
                  WHEN SUM(CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN start_end END)
                         OVER (PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY dt) > 0
                  THEN LAST_VALUE(CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN rn END)
                         IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY dt)
                  END AS rn,
                  LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY dt) AS end_date,
                  SUM(CASE type WHEN 'W' THEN start_end END)
                    OVER (PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY dt) AS is_w,
                  SUM(CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN start_end END)
                    OVER (PARTITION BY brand ORDER BY dt) AS is_a
           FROM   data
           UNPIVOT (dt FOR start_end IN (start_date AS 1, end_date AS -1))
         ) e
         WHERE  ( is_w > 0 OR is_a > 0 )
         AND    start_date < end_date
         AND    t.rn = e.rn
       )
       THEN 'pass'
       ELSE 'not pass'
       END AS pass
FROM   data t
```

Which outputs:

| BRAND | TYPE | START_DATE | END_DATE | PASS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | W | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-06-30 00:00:00 | pass |
| abc | A | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| abc | W | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 2020-09-30 00:00:00 | pass |
| mmm | W | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| mmm | W | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| mmm | A | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | not pass |
| ppp | W | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| ppp | W | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| ppp | A | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 9999-01-01 00:00:00 | pass |
| qqq | W | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| qqq | A | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 2023-09-30 00:00:00 | not pass |
| qqq | W | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| uuu | W | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | pass |
| uuu | A | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 2023-08-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| uuu | W | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| xyz | A | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| xyz | W | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| zzz | W | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | pass |
| zzz | A | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | not pass |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R-3XeEZS)

Comment: I tried the solution in our production database. unfortunatelly it is not usefull.nonidea how to solve it. another tips. thera are around 100mil rows and there are lot of winfows functions that probably slowing the process. it works fine for small dataset.any other idea?